How do I make the model/bones in this scene work correctly on this curve so I can export the model and animation as FBX?
I have been trying to make a model of a roller chain meant to animate along a curve so it goes from 0 degrees X-axis horizontally over the 90-degree curve to 0 degrees vertically on the z-axis.
I have been using the array and curve modifiers to make the individual links follow the curve correctly and can animate it to do what I want in Blender, however, I can't make the animation export to FBX, the model becomes a solid mesh and moves horizontally on the x-axis instead of along the curve. I'm trying to export the model as FBX to import it into Pixelartor
I have added bones to the scene in an attempt to link the chain to the rig and then export it but I can't get the bones to function correctly using spline IK or follow path constraints as it will not follow the curve, the best I can get is the bones being completely straight but aligned with the end of the curve, I also can't get the bones to move, rotate, trying to parent/child them in a chain to arrange them manually doesn't work because the bones stay stationary and wot budge, but I have barely ever used or done anything with bones in Blender so I'm probably missing something.
The attached images shows the chain model with the array and curve modifiers, and the bones are not lining up with the curve, Image one shows the bones without a constraint, image 2 shows the bones with the spline IK constraint.   
